# Как найти дубликаты в массиве и вывести?

Tags: kotlin

Есть массив строк - **("C", "A", "B", "B", "G", "A", "C", "H", "A", "F", "F", "F", "C", "F")**

Нужно найти количество дубликатов у оригинала.

Выхлоп должен быть в виде списка объектов, где у объекта есть два поля - буква оригинала и массив дубликатов:

**С -> С, С**

**A -> A,A**

**B -> B**

**F -> F,F,F**

Чтобы это сделать я прохожусь по всему списку и сравниваю первый элемент с каждым остальным и если есть совпадение, то сохраняю в отдельный объект дубликат вместе с оригиналом, а сам дубликат удаляю из списка. Когда доходим до конца, то удаляем также и первый элемент, чтобы лишний раз не проходиться по списку и приступить к следующим буквам, которые остались. Остальные буквы без дубликатов в конечный массив не добавляется. До тех пор пока изначальный массив не закончится

Но вместого нужного результата получается такой выхлоп:

**C [C, C]**

**A [A, A]**

**B [B]**

**F [F]**

**C [C]**

```
data class Result(var orig : String, var dup : MutableList<String>)

val list = mutableListOf("C", "A", "B", "B", "G", "A", "C", "H", "A", "F", "F", "F", "C", "F")
        val listResult = mutableListOf<Result>()

        while (list.size > 0) {
            val tempList = mutableListOf<String>()
            tempList.addAll(list)

            val result = Result(list[0], mutableListOf())

            tempList.forEachIndexed { index, value ->
                if (index == 0 && tempList.size > 1) return@forEachIndexed
                if (tempList[0] == value) {
                    result.dup.add(value)
                    list.removeAt(index)
                }
            }

            if (list.size > 0) list.removeAt(0)

            if (result.dup.isNotEmpty()) {
                listResult.add(result)
            }
        }

        listResult.forEach {
            Log.d("Result", "!!! "+it.orig +" " +it.dup.toString())
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете создать HashMap где ключом будет ваше строка, а значением список ваших строк.

И проходите по вашему списку и если такой ключ уже есть то просто добавляете в список ещё одну строку, если нет то добавляете новый ключ

Comment: Проблема в том, что я скинул упрощённый способ, так как в реальности будет список объектов вместо обычных букв, где сравнение будет идти по полю, чтобы в итоге был один объект и его дубликаты, которые находились бы по совпадению с полем с оригиналом. И хотелось бы удалять уже обработанные элементы, что в последующей итерации мы их не затрагивали и не тратили время.

Comment: Объекты одного типа или разного?

Comment: Да, объекты одного типа с полями id и string. И нужно будет находить дубликаты по string и формировать их в тот же массив result, где будет уже будут поля `orig : SomeObject, dup: List<SomeObject>`

Comment: Ну так если объекты одного типа то что мешает их положить в мапу? Даже если они были бы разного типа то можно было бы обощить одним интерфейсом

Comment: Можно и так, но мне нужно их ещё вытащить из общего списка с наименьшим количеством обходов, удаляя из общего списка после того как добавили в результирующий массив.

Comment: Изначально приходит обычный массив из объектов одного типа, который нужно сформировать в виде оригинальный объект и список дубликатов

Comment: Ну сделай что-то типа стека. Делаешь pop элемент извлекается из стека и его уже кладешь в мапу и не придется много раз проходить по всему списку

Comment: Разве из стека можно делать pop из середины массива, где может оказаться дубликат?

Comment: Нет, а тебе важно из середины тянуть?

Comment: Тогда просто список из которого ты вытягиваешь элемент из середины и каждый раз список будет меньше. Будет меньше прогонов по списку

Comment: Мне надо не только первый элемент дропать, но и все дубликаты, которые могут оказаться в разных местах.

В данный момент я так и делаю, дропаю дубликаты и в конце прохода сам первый элемент, но по итогу получается не тот результат который хотелось бы

Comment: Ну попробуй просто за один проход по всем элементам их раскидать по мапе. А потом уже из мапы будешь спокойно доставать нужные элементы за O(1)

Answer (score 1):

```
data class Result(var orig: String, var dup: MutableList<String>)

fun main() {

    val list = mutableListOf("C", "A", "B", "B", "G", "A", "C", "H", "A", "F", "F", "F", "C", "F")
    val result = list.groupingBy { it }.aggregate { key, accumulator: Result?, element, first ->
        when {
            first -> Result(key, mutableListOf())
            else -> accumulator!!.apply { dup.add(element) }
        }!!
    }.values.filter { it.dup.isNotEmpty() }

    println(result) // [Result(orig=C, dup=[C, C]), Result(orig=A, dup=[A, A]), Result(orig=B, dup=[B]), Result(orig=F, dup=[F, F, F])]
}
```